# Glass mapper v2 how to fallback to default language

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, glass-mapper

I am using glass mapper v2 in my project. Glass Mapper working great, but in case I added new language to site, glass mapper can't read a lot of properties and I am getting Null Reference errors. 
I would like to have glass mapper behavior like read Default Sitecore Language data in case language is skipped.
Is it real ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Glass is just an ORM for Sitecore, and does not handle any of the data processing or retrieval of items that may go on within Sitecore processes.

If you need language fallback then consider using the [Language Fallback module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Language_Fallback.aspx) or the [Field Fallback module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Field_Fallback.aspx) depending on your needs. Both are available from the Sitecore Marketplace.